# JAudiotagger java.lang.VerifyError in android

Tags: java, android, id3, id3-tag

I am trying to create an audio tag editor refering to these

http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/

and

[JAudioTagger and Android - Change a value in an mp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447145/jaudiotagger-and-android-change-a-value-in-an-mp3)

and

[Jaudiotagger ID3 TAG for android - can set artwork but cannot set other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530339/jaudiotagger-id3-tag-for-android-can-set-artwork-but-cannot-set-other-fields)

which library is needed to be imported in to the project so that I donot get `java.lang.VerifyError`

I am trying the code with this library

`jaudiotagger-2.2.5.jar`

which I Found from here

https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/downloads

this is the code

```
try {
    File file = new File(Data);
    TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
    AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
    Tag newTag = audioFile.getTag();
    newTag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM,"October");
    newTag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,"U2");
    audioFile.commit(); 
} catch (CannotReadException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TagException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ReadOnlyFileException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CannotWriteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the log cat

```
12-07 16:56:10.618: D/dalvikvm(738): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 137K, 11% free 6210K/6919K, paused 59ms
12-07 16:56:11.358: I/dalvikvm(738): Could not find method org.jaudiotagger.tag.TagOptionSingleton.getInstance, referenced from method com.example.scrlltabs3.songManagerDialog$3.onClick
12-07 16:56:11.358: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY: unable to resolve static method 11628: Lorg/jaudiotagger/tag/TagOptionSingleton;.getInstance ()Lorg/jaudiotagger/tag/TagOptionSingleton;
12-07 16:56:11.368: D/dalvikvm(738): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
12-07 16:56:11.368: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1667 (Lorg/jaudiotagger/audio/exceptions/CannotReadException;)
12-07 16:56:11.378: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2b
12-07 16:56:11.378: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/scrlltabs3/songManagerDialog$3;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-07 16:56:11.378: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002b
12-07 16:56:11.388: W/dalvikvm(738): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/scrlltabs3/songManagerDialog$3;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-07 16:56:11.388: W/dalvikvm(738): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/scrlltabs3/songManagerDialog$3;
12-07 16:56:11.388: D/AndroidRuntime(738): Shutting down VM
12-07 16:56:11.398: W/dalvikvm(738): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/scrlltabs3/songManagerDialog$3
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.example.scrlltabs3.songManagerDialog.onCreate(songManagerDialog.java:68)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-07 16:56:11.428: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is there in line 68 of SongManagerDialog.java?

Comment: @ overide for public void onClick(View v)

Comment: Are you using an IDE like eclipse or netbeans? How do you compile your code?

Comment: I suspect this line is causing the Verify issue **TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);**

Comment: is eclipse causing this error, but the question  I referred on SO says we need to use it

Comment: The error says that in the code you are referencing that line but, it does not exist in the jaudio-tagger jar file hence, verifier error. What does that line do?

Comment: Can you replace **audioFile.commit()** with **AudioFileIO.write(audioFile)**

Comment: some library has gone , project is not working will update later thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the error, it is easy to point out that the following line is causing the `Verify` error

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
```

> Could not find method
>   org.jaudiotagger.tag.TagOptionSingleton.getInstance, referenced from
>   method com.example.scrlltabs3.songManagerDialog$3.onClick

Googling the issue I came across the following stackoverflow question/answer that describes the same issue and offers a solution by replacing:

```
audioFile.commit();
```

with

```
AudioFileIO.write(audioFile)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447145/jaudiotagger-and-android-change-a-value-in-an-mp3/6667742#6667742) the question and with above solution. If this resolved your issue then don't forget to give the answerer **Paul Taylor** in that answer an upvote.

**java.lang.verifyError** happens when JVM's bytecode verifier try to verify all the byte code before execution and fail when it finds inconsistencies and these inconsistencies can rise due to many factors such as

- Compiling against one library and using a different one during run time
- Individual compilation of class that have other classes depend on it
- Others listed in the link to tutorial

A detailed explanation about the VerifyError with examples can be found [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror/).

See the examples in the above link which demonstrate how verify error is thrown by JVM.